# How to keep an inclined driveway clear of snow?

Tags: weather

If a driveway has a fairly steep (~15 degrees?) incline, is there a good hack to use that incline to help keep it less snowed-in during heavy snowfalls - say, 1 foot at least?

I considered using cardboard from large boxes on the driveway, but it's too big to be realistically covered; and if the snow is wet, the cardboard becomes soggy and at best, rips up when trying to move cardboard+snow; at worst, freezes to driveway itself.

Salting is the obvious first approach, and the incline clearly helps as the melted snowwater flows downhill; but for a large snowfall it is clearly nowhere near enough to make even a small improvement.

Answer (score 2):

Get a heavy, reinforced plastic tarpaulin large enough to cover the driveway (or multiple standard tarps, lapped with the ones toward the top of the hill over the lower ones), and make sure it's laid out before the snow gets well started.  Once the snow has stopped, find the bottom corners of each tarp and drag the tarp down slope, taking the snow with it.  Once it's clear of the driveway, drag the corners back over the tarp to clear the snow off the tarp itself.

Comment: with any significant snowfall, and given the large size of a typical driveway, it may well be impossible to move the tarp, even going downhill. Snow is **heavy**, especially when it's nearer to freezing temps and the snow is wet rather than dry.